# Easiest option to send emails from PHP?

Tags: php, drupal, email

I am developing social service in Drupal. There is need to send notifications to registered users.

Which option would be the *easiest* to integrate Drupal with and to send notifications to users?

- Amazon SES,
- Google App Engine,
- third party provider (like Sendgrid/PostageApp/CritSend)

SES/GAE are *clear winners* from business point of view.

This question is about which option would be the easiest to integrate with *PHP code* and which would provide least headache.

Please note that third party providers are not that easy to maintain, as they might drop emails without right MTA relay (unfortunately I experienced that problem with Sendgrid and another PHP service).

Comment: Is the standard way of sending them from your server's local SMTP server out of the question?

Comment: Oh and.... maybe better suited on `webmasters.stackexchange.com` (SCNR)

Comment: Well, do you know how to stick the ones from above with SMTP, except the third option? I'm not.

Comment: @nrph why do you need a third party provider in the first place?

Comment: @Pekka - because of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532211/experiences-in-mailing-to-registered-users#4532265

Comment: @nrph fair points. But remember that @andre is talking about really massive amounts of mail. You might still be able to use a local service at first, at least initially - you would have to talk to your provider about the points mentioned in @andre's excellent list, though (Edit: I just saw that you mention 50,000 mails/month - okay, that is indeed probably best done using a 3rd party provider.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), a PHP library that can easily send mails via any [SMTP](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/smtp-transport) server, SendGrid will provide you with an SMTP server that you can use I believe.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion app engine(python). only a couple lines of code to create webservice to send out e-mail in python.

you just do simple post from cURL via PHP to sent email. easy as pie. Maybe later I will post a little snippet to achieve this :P.

Comment: @Marb B wise-ass :). you could write a simple rest interface. Then simply connect to it via cURL. Then have you scaling e-mail instead of that piece of crap software Drupal.

Comment: Drupal is NOT a piece of crap software. I'm really dissapointed by your judgement.

Comment: http://talks.php.net/show/drupal08/32 => 51.37 transactions is per second is NOT good if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

These days, handling email in house is a royal PITA. I recommend [mailchimp](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) instead.

Comment: Also note http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Answer (score 0):

Just want to throw [PostageApp's](http://www.postageapp.com/) hat into the ring. We've got some [documentation](http://help.postageapp.com/kb/api/plugins) on integration with PHP and our API is one of the cleanest and easiest to use around.

We're also exploring an integration with Amazon SES to capitalize on their great prices (And the free option!) so you might be able to use both? Happy to answer questions should you have any.